# Why does this php array sorting function generate warnings

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I found an array sorting function on the php manual site which does exactly what I want, but it generates warnings and I have been trying to work out why and how to stop them. Any advice much appreaciated.

```
function fnArrayOrderby(){
//function to sort a database type array of rows by the values in one or more column
//source http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php - user notes
//example of use -> $sorted = fnArrayOrderby($data, 'volume', SORT_DESC, 'edition', SORT_ASC);

$args = func_get_args(); //Gets an array of the function's argument list (which can vary in length)
//echo "sorting on ".$args[1];
$data = array_shift($args); //Shift an element off the beginning of array
foreach ($args as $n => $field) {
    if (is_string($field)) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $row)
            $tmp[$key] = $row[$field];
        $args[$n] = $tmp;
        }
}
$args[] = &$data;
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args);
 return array_pop($args);
}
```

the warnings generated are

- PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .. for the
  line " foreach ($data as $key => $row)"
- PHP Warning: 
  array_multisort(): Argument #5 is expected to be an array or a sort
  flag  ... for the line call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args)

Comment: array_shift doesn't return an array

Comment: @tkausl: Unless the value in the array happens to be an array.

Comment: Right, let me rephraze it: `array_shift` does not return the array passed and shifted but the value which got shifted out of the passed array. This function takes the array by-reference, so the original array gets changed.

Comment: what's your goal? are there not enough [array sorting methods](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)?

Comment: I'd be interested in looking at the link to the specific *"array sorting function on the php manual site"*

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#100534 ?

Comment: Could we see the whole thing - as the args passed in are relevant -- or are you callins as per the 'example of use'?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll try and add some explanation now. @Jeff Puckett II I basically wanted to do a fairly simple array sort - a typical usage is that I have an array of data on a set of images and I want to rank them by two criteria and select the four first ranked images. This was the top voted answer on the array_multisort manual page  so it seemed a good option - and indeed it works exactly as expected, except for generating warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I have now worked it out - thanks to the comments, especially from @rivimey which made me realise there probably wasn't anything wrong with the function itself but rather with the way it was being called. It turned out the warnings were being generated when the function was applied to an array which was not set. For example I use the function to sort the array of images associated with a database entry, but if there are no images then the array is not set.
So I have now added the following line to the function
    if (!isset($args[0])) { return;}
Thanks for the help!